# VSCode Experimental Support for Decorators Warning When Trying to Create New Module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I just installed Angular 10 and upgraded VSCode to the latest.

When creating a new module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

const mm = []

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ...mm ],
    exports: [...mm
    ],
    providers: [     
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {

}
```

This decorator error is created:

```
class MaterialModule
Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.ts(1219)
```

And it is only created for the new module.  The existing `app.module.ts` is error free...so it's a bit confusing.

Thoughts?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line in your **tslint.config** to avoid this lint error.

> "experimentalDecorators": true

and also checked the enable experimental decorator option in visual studio setting like below[image]

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled "Angular Language Support" in VSCode and that did the trick.